# Swift/SwiftUI Updating a view within a button without having to press the button

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, view

For each button in my view, it has a QuizProgressView which is a little progress bar. Currently if functions properly and updates when the required values change. However, the update is not actually reflected on the UI until the Button it is within is pressed.

How could I force it to update regardless of whether or not the button has been pressed? It's ideal to keep it within the button so that the layout, spacing etc is all correct.

```
struct QuizOption: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var symbolName: String
//    var progress: Double
    var loadSet: [Question]


struct MenuView: View {
    let onQuizButtonTapped: ([Question]) -> Void
    @State private var menuSelectedSet: [Question]?
    @ObservedObject var scoreManager = QuizScoreManager(startingValues: ["Core": 0, "Behaviour": 0, "Parking": 0, "Emergencies": 0, "RoadPosition": 0, "Intersection": 0, "Theory": 0, "Signs": 0])
    @State private var quizOptionIndex: Int?

    var quizOptions = [
        QuizOption(title: "Core", symbolName: "book", loadSet: questionsCore),
        QuizOption(title: "Behaviour", symbolName: "figure.seated.seatbelt", loadSet: questionsBehaviour),
        QuizOption(title: "Parking", symbolName: "car.circle", loadSet: questionsParking),
        QuizOption(title: "Emergencies", symbolName: "light.beacon.max", loadSet: questionsEmergencies),
        QuizOption(title: "RoadPosition", symbolName: "car.top.lane.dashed.arrowtriangle.inward", loadSet: questionsRoadPosition),
        QuizOption(title: "Intersection", symbolName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath", loadSet: questionsIntersection),
        QuizOption(title: "Theory", symbolName: "questionmark.circle", loadSet: questionsTheory),
        QuizOption(title: "Signs", symbolName: "exclamationmark.octagon", loadSet: questionsSigns),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())], spacing: 10) {
                        ForEach(quizOptions, id: \.self) { quizOption in
                            Button(action: {
                                menuSelectedSet = quizOption.loadSet
                                onQuizButtonTapped(menuSelectedSet ?? [])
                            }) {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                    .frame(height: 200)
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .overlay(
                                        VStack {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Image(systemName: quizOption.symbolName)
                                                .font(.system(size: 60))
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                .frame(height: 90)
                                            //Spacer()
                                            Text(quizOption.title)
                                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                .font(.title)
                                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                                .frame(height: 50)
                                            QuizProgressView(quizTitle: quizOption.title) //update this on demand
                                            Spacer()
                                        }
                                    )
                                    .padding(5)
                                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.4), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 5)
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 13)
                    Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationTitle("Learn")
        }

    }

}
```

For QuizProgressView

```
struct QuizProgressView: View {
    var quizTitle: String
    @StateObject private var scoreManager = QuizScoreManager(startingValues: ["Core": 0, "Behaviour": 0, "Parking": 0, "Emergencies": 0, "RoadPosition": 0, "Intersection": 0, "Theory": 0, "Signs": 0])
    //let quizOptions: [QuizOption]
    let progressViewHeight: CGFloat = 6
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15
    var questions: [Question] {
        switch quizTitle {
        case "Core":
            return questionsCore
        case "Behaviour":
            return questionsBehaviour
        case "Parking":
            return questionsParking
        case "Emergencies":
            return questionsEmergencies
        case "RoadPosition":
            return questionsRoadPosition
        case "Intersection":
            return questionsIntersection
        case "Theory":
            return questionsTheory
        case "Signs":
            return questionsSigns
        default:
            return []
        }
    }

    private var lastScore: Int {
        return scoreManager.getLastScore(forQuizTitle: quizTitle) ?? 0
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    let progress = Double(lastScore) / Double(questions.count)
                    let progressBarWidth = geo.size.width - cornerRadius * 2
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Capsule()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.4))
                            .frame(height: progressViewHeight)
                        Capsule()
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .frame(width: CGFloat(progress) * progressBarWidth, height: progressViewHeight)
                    }
                    .frame(height: progressViewHeight)
                    .padding(.horizontal, cornerRadius)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

QuizScoreManager, for passing data into QuizProgressView:

```
class QuizScoreManager: ObservableObject {
    
    struct QuizScore: Codable {
        let date: Date
        let score: Int
        let quizTitle: String
    }
    
    // Dictionary to store the starting values for each quiz
    var startingValues: [String: Int]
    
    @Published var scores: [QuizScore] = []
    
    // Initialize the starting values for each quiz
    init(startingValues: [String: Int]) {
        self.startingValues = startingValues
        loadScores()
    }
    
    func addScore(score: Int, quizTitle: String) {
        let quizScore = QuizScore(date: Date(), score: score, quizTitle: quizTitle)
        scores.append(quizScore)
        saveScores()
        print("just updated \(quizTitle) score to: \(score)")
    }
    
    func getScores(forQuizTitle quizTitle: String) -> [QuizScore] {
        return scores.filter { $0.quizTitle == quizTitle }
    }
    
    private func saveScores() {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(scores) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "quizScores")
        }
    }
    
    func printScores() {
        loadScores()
        for score in scores {
            print("Quiz Title: \(score.quizTitle), Score: \(score.score), Date: \(score.date)")
        }
    }

    func getLastScore(forQuizTitle quizTitle: String) -> Int? {
        let lastScore = scores.filter { $0.quizTitle == quizTitle }.last?.score
        print("QuizProgressView updated at \(Date())")
        return lastScore
    }

    private func loadScores() {
        if let savedScores = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "quizScores") as? Data {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let loadedScores = try? decoder.decode([QuizScore].self, from: savedScores) {
                scores = loadedScores
            }
        }
        
        // Set the starting value for each quiz
        for (quizTitle, startingValue) in startingValues {
            if scores.filter({ $0.quizTitle == quizTitle }).count == 0 {
                let quizScore = QuizScore(date: Date(), score: startingValue, quizTitle: quizTitle)
                scores.append(quizScore)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView, where all the views are presented:

```
class Qmodel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var contentSelectedSet: [Question] = []  // <-- here
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isQuizViewShowing = false
    @StateObject var model = Qmodel()  // <-- here
    @State var hasSelectedSet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            MenuView(onQuizButtonTapped: { menuSelectedSet in
                model.contentSelectedSet = menuSelectedSet
                hasSelectedSet = true
                isQuizViewShowing = true
            })
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "book.fill")
                Text("Learn")
            }
            PracticeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "chart.bar.fill")
                    Text("Practice")
                }
            Text("SettingsView")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                    Text("Settings")
                }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isQuizViewShowing) {
            if hasSelectedSet {
                QuizView(isPresented: $isQuizViewShowing,
                         selectedSet: model.contentSelectedSet)
            }
            else {
                Text("Selected set is nil")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `@State var quizOptions ...`

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to post a reproducible example?

Comment: updated my answer in view of your new code edit. Note, your code has still many missing parts and cannot be compiled. In particualr it is missing the important `QuizScoreManager` that would help in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

In view of your new code, `...to have a view QuizProgressView update whenever a value lastScore changes`, try this setup.

In `MenuView` when you call `QuizProgressView(quizTitle: quizOption.title)` you are creating a new
`@StateObject private var scoreManager ...` at every iteration of the loop, this is the main problem.

You should declare `@StateObject private var scoreManager ...` in `MenuView` and pass it to the `QuizProgressView`, for example using `@EnvironmentObject`.

Try this approach as shown in the pseudo-code, since the code you provide is not complete
and cannot be compiled.

Whenever the `scoreManager` (lastScore) values are changed, the UI should update.

```
 struct MenuView: View {
     let onQuizButtonTapped: ([Question]) -> Void
     @State private var menuSelectedSet: [Question]?

     // -- here
     @StateObject private var scoreManager = QuizScoreManager(startingValues: ["Core": 0, "Behaviour": 0, "Parking": 0, "Emergencies": 0, "RoadPosition": 0, "Intersection": 0, "Theory": 0, "Signs": 0])
     .....
     var body: some View {
         NavigationView {
          .....
         }
          .environmentObject(scoreManager)  // <-- here
   }
    .....

 
 struct QuizProgressView: View {
     @EnvironmentObject var scoreManager: QuizScoreManager  // <-- here
     ...
 }
```

Comment: I gave this a go, and while I cant be certain if I implemented it correctly, I couldn't get QuizProgressView to update live or when the button was pressed. I'll update the question to include all the code so that it should be compilable and will see if I can get your suggested fix to work.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your post, you are creating the progress view within the button like this:

```swift
QuizProgressView(quizTitle: quizOption.title)
```

It's difficult to see where this progress View is getting the progress information from that it's supposed to be displaying. Maybe it's accessing some kind of global data that is being updated externally? This won't work - it will probably display the state of progress correctly when first created, but it won't update when the data changes.

The way to get it to track the progress (your "source of truth") is to build in a dependency to the data using a `State` variable or an `ObservedObject`. Here's how it might look if you did it with a State variable:

```swift
@State private var progress = 0.0
:
:
QuizProgressView(quizTitle: quizOption.title, progress: progress)
```

Your QuizProgressView might then look something like this (as a minimum):

```swift
struct QuizProgressView: View {
    private var quizTitle: String
    private var progress: Double

    init(quizTitle:String, progress: Double) {
        self.quizTitle = quizTitle
        self.progress = progress
    }

    var body: some View {
        ProgressView(value: progress)
    }
}
```

[You could also pass in the progress to the sub-view using a `Binding` to the `State` variable. But since the progress view is just a display-only view of the data, it is not necessary in this case.]

In summary, you need to remember that a `View` is exactly that - it is a view of some data. If the data can change and you want the view to be updated when it does then you need to build in a dependency to the data. This is done using a `State` variable, a `Binding` or an `ObservedObject`.

For display-only sub-views, an update to a simple value can be "pushed" to a sub-view by passing the value to init, as illustrated above. Using this technique, it is the parent view that needs to be bound to the data using a `State` variable, a `Binding` or an `ObservedObject`, otherwise updates won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Following from my previous answer above, an alternative approach would be to make your `QuizOption` observable.

1. Change `QuizOption` to a class and implement `ObservableObject`:

```swift
class QuizOption: Identifiable, Hashable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var symbolName: String
    @Published var progress = 0.0
    var loadSet: [Question]
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), title: String, symbolName: String, loadSet: [Question]) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.symbolName = symbolName
        self.loadSet = loadSet
    }
    static func == (lhs: QuizOption, rhs: QuizOption) -> Bool {
        lhs.title == rhs.title
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(title)
    }
}
```

2. Pass the quiz option to the progress view:

```swift
QuizProgressView(quizOption: quizOption)
```

3. Observe the quiz option in the progress view:

```swift
struct QuizProgressView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var quizOption: QuizOption

    init(quizOption: QuizOption) {
        self.quizOption = quizOption
    }

    var body: some View {
        ProgressView(value: quizOption.progress)
    }
}
```

4 There is a complication, because the options are being created in `MenuView` (instead of being passed in). To preserve the array between View incarnations, it might be sufficient to wrap it as a `State` variable:

```swift
    @State var quizOptions = [...
```

While we're at it, `QuizScoreManager` is also being created in `MenuView`, so it should be wrapped as a `StateObject`, not as an `ObserveredObject`:

```swift
@StateObject var scoreManager = QuizScoreManager(startingValues: ["Core": 0, "Behaviour": 0, "Parking": 0, "Emergencies": 0, "RoadPosition": 0, "Intersection": 0, "Theory": 0, "Signs": 0])
```

Comment: What I should have included in the question originally is the code for QuizProgressView itself. I don't think the approach of 'progress' being a part of QuizOption is ideal, because the progress value itself is retrieved from a datastore in QuizProgressView, and used to update the progress bar. I will add the code for QuizProgressView to the question to give you a bit more context about what I'm saying.

Comment: OK. I would suggest that your datasource should hold a collection of ```ObservableObject```, one for each progress value. Then you need to supply the progress view with the relevant progress object as per steps 2 and 3 provided previously. In any case, the data you want to track must be either a ```State``` variable or be published by an ```ObservedObject``` as per my other answer.